# Song Ratings (Stars) Missing in iTunes!

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, ratings

I routinely rate songs on my iPhone in the Music app with the 1-5 star system.

I just plugged my iPhone into my computer and saw in iTunes (on the "Music" tab under "Devices") ALL OF MY SONG RATINGS ARE GONE. When I right click on a particular song and click "Get Info", the star ratings are gone from there, too.

How can I see the star ratings in iTunes?

OS X 10.10.4 (2013 rMBP)  --  iTunes 12.2.0.145  --  iOS 8.3 (iPhone 4S)

Comment: You mean one song that had "n" stars now has 0 stars? Or is it replaced by a heart icon?

Comment: I mean: every song that had "n" stars, now has no rating whatsoever, as if the song had never been rated before.

Comment: Just updated iPhone to iOS 8.4 and the issue persists.